# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow Join Conditions Substitution

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to implement the following SQL script via Join in Data Flow?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  [landing].[ACODETEMP].[objectid] AS ActObjID, 
  MIN(CASE [landing].[ACODETEMP].[name] WHEN 'Activity Priority' THEN [landing].[ACTIVITYCODE]. 
  [codevalue] END) AS [Activity Priority], 
  MIN(CASE [landing].[ACODETEMP].[name] WHEN 'Area' THEN [landing].[ACTIVITYCODE].[codevalue] END) AS Area, 
  ...
FROM            
  [landing].[ACODETEMP]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [landing].[ACTIVITYCODE] ON [landing].[ACODETEMP].[name] = [landing].[ACTIVITYCODE].[codetypename] 
  AND [landing].[ACODETEMP].[activitycodeobjectid] = [landing].[ACTIVITYCODE].[objected] 
  AND [landing].[ACODETEMP].[name] IN ('Activity Priority', 'Area', '...')
  GROUP BY [landing].[ACODETEMP].[objected]
```

I don't know how to implement the substitution like: IN ('Activity Priority', 'Area', '...')

[image]

Comment: You can save `'Activity Priority', 'Area', '...'` to another file such csv file. Then set it as a data source and join it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked but if they didn't make an "in" available then do an series of "==" and "or"'s within brace brackets

example (name == 'Activity Priority' || name == 'Area' || ... )

It is a lot of typing but will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `'Activity Priority', 'Area', '...'` to another file such csv file. Then set it as a data source and join it.

For example:

1. I saved `John,Jane,Eloise` into a txt or csv, as follows:
   [image]
2. Set it as a data source named `FilterSource` in data flow, as follows:
   [image]
3. This is the left outer join:
   [image]
4. After the left outer join, you can set a right outer join to `FilterSource`:
   [image]
5. Then it will filter the names, it has the same effect as `in (John,Jane,Eloise)`.
   [image]

Comment: Hi @Pajkatt, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

You can always click "Custom (cross) join" and type in your expression there